# how to pass parameter to url and load page php

Tags: magento2, php

I want to get data by current url, please see my code

```
 if (currenturl = 'https://example.com/delhi.html') {
                       $_GET['location'] = 289;
    }
```

but is not giving data while if we run like

```
https://example.com/delhi.html?location=289
```

then it is getting data. please anyone idea for that

Comment: What function are you using to get direct url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get query string of url from below way in phtml file directly,**

```
echo $this->request->getParam('location');
```

**OR**

If you want to get current url parameter in block file,
need to do using construct parameter,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function getParamsUrl(){
    return $this->request->getParam('location');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. actually i am doing this code in my custom observer in magento2. and getting current url and and i want to pass query string "?location=289" in url  : https://example.com/delhi.html - when we hit this in browser. can you please check for add querystring to this url and then page will load